# Hibernate Query 3 Nested select

Tags: jquery, hibernate, hql

How can I fix this query for currect work?

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery(
    "FROM Rates WHERE amount = 
        (SELECT MIN(amount) FROM
            (SELECT amount FROM Rates
            GROUP BY amount having COUNT(*) = 1))");
```

IntellijIDE compiler shows

`')', ',', FETCH, GROUP, HAVING, IN, ORDER, WHERE or identifier expected, got '(`

and underlines the red line `FROM (SELECT` this `(`

Comment: Please explain better your aim

Comment: Do you want extract all rates where amount is minimum value?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request, you can try this:

```
"FROM Rates r1 WHERE r1.amount in 
    (SELECT MIN(r2.amount) FROM Rates r2
        GROUP BY r2.amount having COUNT(r2.amount) = 1))"
```

Tell me if it's OK